# How to update one sub-document in an embedded list with Ecto?

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a document with an embedded list of sub-docs. How do I update/change one particular document in the embedded list with Ecto?

```
defmodule MyApp.Thing do
  use MyApp.Model

  schema "things" do
    embeds_many :users,  User
  end
end


defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Model

  embedded_schema do
    field :name,  :string
    field :email, :string
    field :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.Model do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      use MyApp.Web, :model
      @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
      @foreign_key_type :binary_id # For associations
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far is to generate a list of all users except the one I want to update and make a new list of the one user's changeset and the other users and then `put_embed` this list on the thing. It works but it feels like there must be a more elegant solution to this.

```
user        = Enum.find(thing.users, fn user -> user.id == user_id end)
other_users = Enum.filter(thing.users, fn user -> user.id != user_id end)
user_cs     = User.changeset(user, %{email: email})
users       = [user_cs | other_users]

thing
|> Ecto.Changeset.change
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_embed(:users, users)
|> Repo.update
```

**EDIT:** I just discovered a serious pitfall with this "solution". The untouched users get updated as well which can be a problem with concurring calls (race condition). So there has to be another solution.